# Do you have any experience with testosterone treatment to speed the onset of puberty?

Tags: teen, medicine

My son turned 14 last fall, but has yet to start puberty. He's always been small for his age, but it's become more pronounced as his friends and classmates hit their growth spurts. His doctors have done blood tests and x-rays and confirmed there is nothing wrong, though we're told his body is at the developmental stage of an average 10 year-old.

The doctors recommended a course of testosterone injections. We did some research and doctors appear to universally recommend this. We learned that while this treatment jump-starts puberty and kicks off a growth spurt, studies have shown there is no ultimate size different when fully grown between those who have the treatment and those who don't.

My son has good friends and has learned to accept his size. But nonetheless he's eager for puberty to begin before he starts high school. The doctors we've spoken to recommend the procedure for the psychological benefit of catching up to his peers.

In spite of the research we're still nervous about this. It would help if we had a testimonial from a teenager or parents who have been through this.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the kind of question we can really answer. We can't provide medical advice, and while the experience of someone who has been through it might feel more "real" than a doctor's opinion, it doesn't actually give you more information. Your doctor is the best guide to medical treatment and we can only suggest that you follow their advice.

Comment: To get more medical information, you could consider asking on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ . However, note that they, too, cannot give individual medical advice and cannot replace professional medical advice.

Comment: I don’t see a difference between this question and the one linked [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/should-we-circumcise-our-son?r=SearchResults). In both cases, the OP is looking for other parents/people’s *experiences* not medical advice. Unless I’m interpreting this question incorrectly, this poster already has medical advice, but wants additional information to supplement it. A parent wanting advice on whether or not to help their teen with a physical issue that affects their psychological well being is allowed here, is it not?

Comment: I think this question is fine as it is.  It's not asking for medical advice, it's asking for the experiences of other parents who went through this process *generally*.  I don't know if this is a common enough thing that you'll get an answer, but I think it's fine to ask.

Comment: @Jax the question you link was looking for information about non-medical aspects of circumcision. This question is looking for anecdotes about recommended medical treatment. There is an important difference.

Comment: While I personally didn't go through this as a parent, a very close friend of mine in high school went through hormonal issues that delayed her development and puberty about 2-3 years after the rest of us. I remember how insecure she was, and it made me sad but she eventually caught up. Back then I am not sure if the options teenagers have nowadays were available, and she turned out just fine without them.. so I think this decision is purely personal and comes down to what works best for you and your son. I don't think any form of medical advice can substitute that ;) Good luck to you both!

Comment: First of all, does your son want to receive the hormonal treatment? You should never force something that is not medically necessary on your son without his consent. Second of all, I think you should talk to a medical professional about the full implications of the hormonal treatment if you have not done so already.

Comment: @Jax, I see several differences between giving a son hormonal treatment and circumcision. A 14 year old boy can consent to hormonal treatment, whereas a newborn baby cannot consent to circumcision. Additionally, hormonal treatment will make a much greater impact on a boy's health and appearance than circumcision. Finally, circumcision has long-term implications (it cannot be reversed) unlike hormonal treatment (the OP's son will have the same adult height either way).